# pandas e sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python, sqlalchemy

Olá, estou tentando criar uma conexão de banco de dados mysql num programa python, segue o código

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/cadastro')
```

agora segue o erro que esse código gera:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-eaabdee0218f> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import sqlalchemy
----> 3 engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/cadastro')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
    421     strategy = kwargs.pop("strategy", default_strategy)
    422     strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy]
--> 423     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
    424 
    425 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
     85                 if k in kwargs:
     86                     dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k)
---> 87             dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
     88 
     89         dialect_args["dbapi"] = dbapi

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\pymysql.py in dbapi(cls)
     60     @classmethod
     61     def dbapi(cls):
---> 62         return __import__("pymysql")
     63 
     64     def is_disconnect(self, e, connection, cursor):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

fico muito grato se vcs puderem me ajudar

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, olhando por cima o problema está que você está tentando usar o modulo 'pymysql' e não o importou.
Segue esse link da documentação do sqlalchemy que mostra como fazer a conexão: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html, logo no inicio mostra como.
Espero que ajude!!!

Comment: deu certo, obrigado